# Is there a Javascript Scheme interpretter that allows javascript calls from within?

Tags: javascript, scheme

I'm trying to create a Scheme interface for a user, for using my client side Javascript stuff.
The thing is, I don't want the interpreter to simply work like a scheme interpreter.

I just want the ability to provide the users with some trivial primitive functions which are implemented in Javascript.

The user basically uses Scheme to use my primitive functions (like say one that writes things using `document.write()` function) in any fancy way like he wants(conditionally, recursively, iteratively , etc.).

Is there some way I could do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BiwaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/) does what you want.

Comment: Is there a guide or something on BiwaScheme? I couldn't find a guide for a starter who has just learnt some Scheme.
Is there some place where I can read up about how to use BiwaScheme like that?

Comment: http://jcubic.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/how-to-use-biwascheme/  Not the best English but it covers the basics

Comment: @learner This page has some interesting examples: https://github.com/biwascheme/biwascheme/wiki/Extending-Scheme-interpreter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [WhaleSong](http://hashcollision.org/whalesong/) which compiles (a subset of) Racket to JavaScript.